# Rails 5 - How to get serializable_hash for activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, serialization

In rails 5, I am trying to get a data in `serializable_hash` format. First set of data format is in correct but second set of data is in different format. 
The Comment module works like parent and children format, one comment has_many comments by adding parent_comment_id.

For parent comment, now data is `{id: 77, name: "l1", verified: true, category: "Movie", slug: "l1", …}`

For child comment, data is coming like `{id: 78, name: "l2", category_id: 61, …}`

Here I need to get second set of data for comments as same as first format. I have tried using `serializable_hash` but it supports only single row. How can I achieve this for all comments(has_many association)?

Answer (score 1):

You can include sub objects when accessing a serializable_hash by using the :include option, like this:

```
parent.serializable_hash(include: ["comments"])
```